# How to compute the operator Schmidt decomposition of a matrix using python

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, svd, matrix-decomposition

> How to do [THIS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/662215/173452) in python?

Currently, I can transform a 4X4 matrix 'A' into its bipartite shape [2,2,2,2], as described in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/662215/173452).
Once performing the SVD on the latter (the transformed version of 'A') using python via:

- [NumPy SVD](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html): `U, S, Vh = numpy.linalg.svd(A)`
- [PyTorch SVD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.svd.html): `U, S, Vh = torch.linalg.svd(A)`

and it turns out (in both cases):

- `U.shape = Vh.shape = [2,2,2,2]`
- `S.shape = [2,2,2]`

I want to write a function:

```
def to_schmidt(A):
    U, S, Vh = torch.linalg.svd(A)
    
    #
    # Do stuff with U, S, and Vh
    #
    
    return [[s1, ..., s4], [B1, ..., B4], [C1, ..., C4]]
```

Which returns a list of the s's' B's, and C's just as described in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/662215/173452). Just to clarify (using PyTorch in the example):

```
should_be_the_original_matrix_A = None
for i in range(4):
    if should_be_the_original_matrix_A = None:
        should_be_the_original_matrix_A = s[i] * torch.kron(B[i], C[i])
    else:
        should_be_the_original_matrix_A += s[i] * torch.kron(B[i], C[i])

#
# The one with A_{i}{j} with i,j = 0, 1, 2, 3
# or alternatively A.shape= [4,4], i.e.
# before the transformation to the bipartite rep.
#
```

The answer given there uses Mathematica, but as I'm not familiar with it:

**How to complete this function?**

Hopefully, using PyTorch, NumPy, or anything convertible to them, fairly trivially.